Unable to set a text to my edittext in the dialog box
I have created an edit text in my dialog box and i want to set a particular text to it but i am unable to do so.
This is my code for the dialog box.
private void setStaticMethod(EditText editText1) {
    // Inflate the custom dialog layout
    View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null);

    // Retrieve views from the layout
    EditText editText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
    Spinner fontSpinner = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.fontSpinner);
    Spinner colorSpinner = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.colorSpinner);
    Button button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    TextView smallFont = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.smallFont);
    TextView largeFont = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.largeFont);
    CheckBox marqueeRtoL = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.marqueeRtoL);
    CheckBox marqueeLtoR = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.marqueeLtoR);

    editText.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
    copyEditTextAttributes(editText1, editText);

    // Create AlertDialog Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TemplateActivity.this);
    builder.setView(dialogView); // Set the custom layout to the dialog

    // Create and show the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show(); 

}
this is the code where the edit text is created in the layout.
 EditText editText = new EditText(this);
                editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
                editText.setText(staticMessage.title); // Set the static title as the text
                editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(staticMessage.color));
                editText.setTextSize(staticMessage.size);

                setOnTouch(editText, "static");

this is the method that calls the first defined method.
private void setOnTouch(EditText editText, String message) {
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (message.equals("normal")) {
                    setMethod(editText);
                } else if (message.equals("static")) {
                    setStaticMethod(editText);
                }
                return true; // Returning true means the touch event is consumed
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

I want to set the text of edittext1 to my edittext in the dialog box but nothing shows up on the screen. the edit text is blank and behaves normally. I even printed out the value of edittext1.getText().toString() and it prints correctly. Can someone please help me with this i have been struggling since the last three days.

Can you add the main layout code and where you have initialized editText1?

i have added it above.

Try to set id of editText like this and see if it works editText.setId(1).

I think while you are creating EditText you only initialized the Element but never added UI Characteristic,like width and height, and added it to a Container of specific Context.
e.g. if you want it inside a LinearLayout add
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(<context>);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);//or LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
layout.addView(editText);

Below is the Code Try it
      EditText editText = new EditText(this);
      editText.setLayoutParams(new 
      LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
                editText.setText(staticMessage.title);
                
      editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(staticMessage.color));
                editText.setTextSize(staticMessage.size);

      LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      layout.addView(editText);

      setOnTouch(editText, "static");

